# IBM Watson Visual Recognition Service in Bluemix always returning empty content

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I'm trying to test the IBM Watson Visual Recognition Service in Bluemix using the API tester.

1st I want to get the list of valid labels:

1. I open the API tester: http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/apis/#!/visual-recognition/getLabelService
2. I issue an empty string
3. Response Body: no content, Response Code: 0

While reading the source code of the demo app I was inferring the labels, e.g. "Animal"

1. I open this link: http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/apis/#!/visual-recognition/recognizeLabelsService
2. I upload an images and set label to "Animal"
3. Response Body: no content, Response Code: 0

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The demo app seems to work quite well, at least it recognizes an image of Obama as "person, president, obama" :)

Answer (score 5):

Check out the following links for some examples on how to use the service.

If you were to use the image http://visual-recognition-demo.mybluemix.net/images/63992.jpg.  The post request to Watson would look like the following.

[image: form data for watson]

All the code on the server side (Node.Js) is doing is streaming the image to Watson.

```
    function(req, res) {

        var stream = fs.createReadStream(req.files.imgFile.path);
        var params = {
            image_file: stream
        };

        visualRecognition.recognize(params, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(error.error ? error.error.code || 500 : 500).json({ error: error });
            } else {
                return res.json(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

[Demo allowing you to upload your own image and identify it](http://visual-recognition-demo.mybluemix.net/)

The code for the above app is available [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/image-analysis).